# How to determine at runtime if application is using a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

As the question asks...how to determine at runtime if application is using a UINavigationController?

I need to resolve this in the init method of the View Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot determine if a view controller is inside a navigation controller in the init method as the normal sequence is 
1. The object is initialized
2. The object is pushed onto a navigation controller.

if you know beforehand while initializing the view controller that it is going to be pushed onto a view controller, you could add a new init method like:

```
-(id)initWithBool:(BOOL)willIBePushedOnANavigationController
{
//insert whatever code for specific case for input
[self init];
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is what I decided to do instead of determining during init.  It works, so I guess this is the only real way it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if([self.navigationController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
    NSLog(@"yes it has navigation Controller");

}
else{
    NSLog(@"nope it doesnt have");
}

NSLog(@"See Results Here => %@",[self.navigationController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]);
```

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: This works, but not in the init method.  Is there any way to determine it in the init method?

Comment: How would the view controller know at initialization how it's going to be displayed in the future? Maybe instead of implementing this in the **init** method, you could instead implement it in **viewWillAppear** and perform any layout/style changes there?

Comment: I would prefer to do it in the viewWillAppear but there are performance issues that are causing the layouts to jerk into place.  Perhaps resolving this in init is not possible?